# Sending JSON between localhost ports

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, cors

I had an ASP.NET MVC app running on port 8799 that posted JSON data via an `XMLHttpRequest` to an MVC controller handler.  This pipeline was working perfectly fine.

I recently spun up a second app, this time an Express app running on port 8080, that again posts JSON in the same way (same exact code, using again an `XMLHttpRequest`), to the same MVC controller running on port 8799.  This time, however, it appears as though while the request is received by the controller, there is no data on it.

I'm wondering if this is because I am making a cross-origin request between these two ports.  Going off of this hypothesis, I added the following custom headers to my `web.config` file:

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
  </customHeaders>
```

This does not seem to solve the issue.  How can I debug this problem, I don't seem to be throwing any particularly useful exceptions?

Comment: If you run the endpoint in VS in debug you should be able to catch and step through your code.

Comment: Requests between ports are counted as cross domain and will be restricted by the browser without the correct CORS headers. Either make the ports match or implement CORS on the server. [See here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @Liam, see how I added the custom headers for the ASP.NET app?  Shouldn't that resolve any potential CORS issues?  Additionally, wouldn't a CORS error throw some kind of useful exception in the ASP.NET app?

Comment: Ahh, I just realized that the request being handled by the controller is seen as an `OPTIONS` request, which leads me to believe that CORS is failing somehow (as per this answer: https://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue did turn out to be CORS.  For whatever reason the `web.config` file was not being used by my .NET application.  Thus, I setup CORS setting in my `Startup.cs` file instead, using `services.AddCors()` in my `Configure()` call.